# Pinterest conversion tracking tag for WooCommerce orders

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, pinterest, event-tracking, conversion-tracking

I need to install the Pinterest conversion tag to dynamically track 'value' and 'order_quantity' from WooCommerce orders. The Pinterest tag has 2 parts of Javascript. Part 1 is the Base Code that goes in the header of the site. Part 2 is the Event code that goes in the header of the Checkout.

I think Part 2 is what must be modified below (value and order_quantity need to be changed to pull from WooCommerce orders):

```
<script>
pintrk('track', ' checkout ', {
    value: {{Enhanced Transaction Revenue}},
    order_quantity: {{item.quantity}}
  });
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src=" https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid= 123456789 &event= checkout &noscript=1" /> </noscript>
```

Pinterest conversion tag guide here: https://help.pinterest.com/sites/help/files/pinterest_tag_instructions.pdf

I'm desperate at this point so any help would be greatly appreciated...and rewarded!

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your functions.php and change Your_Tag_ID to match the tag id you have from Pinterest.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'pinterest_tracking' );

function pinterest_tracking( $order_id ) {

// Lets grab the order
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

/**
 * Put your tracking code here
 * You can get the order total etc e.g. $order->get_total();
 */

// This is the order total
$order_total = $order->get_total();
$order_quantity = $order->get_item_count();

?>

<script>
    pintrk('track', 'checkout', {
        {
            value: '<?php echo $order_total ?>',
            order_quantity: '<?php echo $order_quantity ?>',
            currency: 'USD'
        }
    ]);
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=Your_Tag_ID&event=checkout&ed[value]=<?php echo $order_total ?>&ed[order_quantity]=<?php echo $order_quantity ?>&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<?php

}
```

Here are two links that helped me:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-tracking-code-for-the-thanks-page/

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/ad-tools/conversion-tag/

Comment: You forgot the email with hashed data.